# can`t get fieldsArray`s defaultValues in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hook-form

I have the react-hook-form with fieldArray. When I was sending data to server I wrote just

```
const methods = useForm<UserSubmitFormCreate>({
    defaultValues: {
      contactsArray: [{ fio: "", phone_num: "", email: "" }],
    },
    mode: "onChange"
  });
```

But if I have got data from server and have to use this in my fieldArray. I have tried to write this:

```
const methods = useForm<UserSubmitFormCreate>({
    defaultValues: {
      contactsArray: [{ fio: "John", phone_num: "123", email: "abc@abc.com" }],
    },
    mode: "onChange"
  });
```

It did not work.
So strange but in my component I have got variable `fields` and this data is accurate. But in my fields I see nothin. This is light version of my component:

```
const FieldsArrayInput = () => {

  const { control, register } = useFormContext();
  const { fields } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "contactsArray",
  });

  console.log(fields); // [{ fio: "John", phone_num: "123", email: "abc@abc.com" }]

  return (
      {fields.map((field: any, index: number) => {
      
        return (
          <div key={field.id}>
            <input
              placeholder="name"
              {...register(`contactsArray.${index}.fio` as const,
                {
                  shouldUnregister: true,
                  required: { value: someReturnedTrueOaFalse(), message: "someMessage" },
                })
              } />
            <input
              placeholder="email"
              {...register(`contactsArray.${index}.email` as const,
                {
                  shouldUnregister: true,
                  required: { value: someReturnedTrueOaFalse(), message: "someMessage" },
                })
              } />
            <input
              placeholder="phone"
              {...register(`contactsArray.${index}.phone_num` as const,
                {
                  shouldUnregister: true,
                  required: { value: someReturnedTrueOaFalse(), message: "someMessage" },
                })
              } />
          </div>
        );
      })}
  );
};
```

UPD: when I was getting data from server (for example with two objects like this: `[{ fio: "John", phone_num: "123", email: "abc@abc.com" }, { fio: "Elena", phone_num: "456", email: "def@abc.com" }]` ) I saw pair of fields, but it was empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving name and value props to input. That might work.
Like this:

```
     <input
              placeholder="name"
              {...register(`contactsArray.${index}.fio` as const,
                {
                  shouldUnregister: true,
                  required: { value: someReturnedTrueOaFalse(), message: "someMessage" },
                })
              } 
name="fio" value={fio}
     />
```

If it doesn't show value like this try giving `value={field.fio}` OR `value={contactsArray[index].fio}` something like that.